# Enabling target_feature gated language features when using wasm32 simd intrinsics

Tags: rust, simd, intrinsics, webassembly

So I am trying to use core::arch::wasm32::i32x4_* functions in order to compile SIMD intrinsics into WebAssembly.

The intrinsic functions I am trying to use are implemented [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/stdarch/blob/ec6fccd34c30003a7ebf4e7a9dfe4e31f5b76e1b/crates/core_arch/src/wasm32/simd128.rs) and documented [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/arch/wasm32/index.html). Most of these functions are not stable and so I am using rustc 1.45.0-nightly (2020-05-30). In addition, the compiler required that I opt into these options:

```
// https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44839
#![feature(wasm_target_feature)]

// https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/69098
#![feature(target_feature_11)]
```

I see in [mod.rs of wasm32](https://github.com/rust-lang/stdarch/blob/ec6fccd34c30003a7ebf4e7a9dfe4e31f5b76e1b/crates/core_arch/src/wasm32/mod.rs) that the functions I am trying to use are feature gated with `#[cfg(any(target_feature = "simd128", dox))]`

The function I am implementing, looks like this:

```
#[cfg(target_arch = "wasm32")]
#[target_feature(enable = "simd128")]
unsafe fn _dot_simd(&self) -> i32 {
    // use core::arch::wasm32::*;
    core::arch::wasm32::memory_size(3);  /*<-- this line works since it is stable */
    core::arch::wasm32::i32x4_splat(32); /*<-- this line errors */
    42
}
```

If I understand `#[target_feature(enable = "simd128")]` correctly, the code above would work since it forces "simd128" feature be enabled regardless of the hardware. I also tried enabling that feature through `-C target_feature=+simd128` but that also did not change anything. 
The error I am getting is

```
i32x4_splat(32);
   ^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in core::arch::wasm32
```

And the command I run to compile is `wasm-pack build` which under the hood runs:

`cargo build --lib --release --target wasm32-unknown-unknown`

Could you help me see what I am missing?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: Yes! I added a clarifying comment [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/stdarch/commit/676940320103a0465d038602fd97dcfd3e32e531). The rust standard library itself is not by default compiled with these gates enabled and so even when you enable them in your program, they are not present in the standard library binary. You can solve this by getting standard library source with `rustup` and recompiling it with necessary flags.